# How to create this multiple dynamic-id-specific accordion with close button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to create accordion. When I click "Show" I want text "Show" is hidden and the content and "close" button is shown. When I click "close" I want to hide the content and "close" button and show the "Show" button.

Every text must be in the HTML, not in JS. But I connect this to Wordpress dynamic id posts to show and hide more content on the index page.

This is my attempt, but the "Close" button doesn't work.

This must working on multiple id items because I connect this to Wordpress index posts page.

Can I add to change the class for these show/close buttons? I want if I click the "Show" button's parent, another element changes class and if I click the "Close" button's parent, another element changes class?

```js
var $contents = $('.tab-content');
$contents.slice().hide();
$('.tab').click(function() {
  var $target = $('#' + this.id + 'show').show();
  $contents.not($target).hide();
});
```

```css
.tab {
  background: red;
  max-width: 100px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.close {
  border: 1px solid red;
  max-width: 100px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="tab1" class="tab">Show 1</div>
<div id="tab1show" class="tab-content">
  content 1
  <div class="close">close</div>
</div>

<br><br><br>
<div id="tab2" class="tab">Show 2</div>
<div id="tab2show" class="tab-content">
  content 2
  <div class="close">close</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You don't have any click handler for close button. `$('.close').click(...`

Comment: You can add handler fot this fiddle?

Comment: you are just asking other people to do the work you obviously can do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z_acharki/udr01vsq/57/)**.

You've to add a click event for the `close` button too, like :

```js
var $contents = $('.tab-content');
$contents.slice().hide();

$('.tab').click(function() {
  removeNewClass();

  var $target = $('#' + this.id + 'show').show();
  var newClass = 'post' + this.id.split('tab')[1] + 'long';

  $(this).hide().parent().addClass(newClass);
  $('.tab').show();
  $contents.not($target).hide();
});

$('.close').click(function() {
  removeNewClass();

  $(this).parent().hide();
  $(this).parent().prev('.tab').show();

  var $target = $(this).parent();
});

function removeNewClass() {
  $contents.each(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    var postClass = 'post' + id.split('tab')[1];

    $(this).parent().attr("class", postClass);
  });
}
```

```css
.tab {
  background: red;
  max-width: 100px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.close {
  border: 1px solid red;
  max-width: 100px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="post1">
  <div id="tab1" class="tab">Show 1</div>
  <div id="tab1show" class="tab-content">
    content 1
    <div class="close">close</div>
  </div>
</div>


<br><br><br>

<div class="post2">
  <div id="tab2" class="tab">Show 2</div>
  <div id="tab2show" class="tab-content">
    content 2
    <div class="close">close</div>
  </div>

  <br><br><br>
</div>
```

Comment: doesen't work. When i click Show 1 and Show 2 show 1 is disappear.

Comment: Fixed check now please

Comment: ok Thank You but when i click show1 button from post1 i want to add class to post1 dynamicaly named post1long and dynamicaly add post2long to post2 when i click show2 https://jsfiddle.net/udr01vsq/25/

Comment: Check this update https://jsfiddle.net/z_acharki/udr01vsq/36/ , do you want to remove them when we click close ?

Comment: Here we go , check this update https://jsfiddle.net/z_acharki/udr01vsq/55/

Comment: Ok but when i click show1 or show2 the div red with text show1 or show2 isn't hide https://jsfiddle.net/udr01vsq/61/

Answer (score 1):

Add an event on `.close` to do so.

```js
var $contents = $('.tab-content');
$contents.slice().hide();

$('.tab').click(function() {
  var $target = $('#' + this.id + 'show').show();
  $(this).hide();
});

$('.close').click(function(){
  $(this).parent().hide();
  let parentId = $(this).parent().attr('id');
  parentId = parentId.replace('show','');
  
  $('#'+parentId).show();
  
});
```

```css
.tab {background:red; max-width:100px; cursor: pointer;}
.close {border: 1px solid red; max-width:100px; cursor: pointer;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  
  <div id="tab1" class="tab">Show 1</div>
  <div id="tab1show" class="tab-content">
  content 1
  <div class="close">close</div>
  </div>



<br><br><br>
<div id="tab2" class="tab">Show 2</div>
<div id="tab2show" class="tab-content">
  content 2
  <div class="close">close</div>
</div>

<br><br><br>
```

Comment: doesen't work. When i click Show 2 show 1 is disappear.

Comment: I've udpated the snippet, try now.

Comment: ok Thank You but when i click show1 button from post1 i want to add class to post1 dynamicaly named .long and dynamicaly add .long to post2 when i click show2 https://jsfiddle.net/udr01vsq/32/

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
var $contents = $('.tab-content');
$contents.slice().hide();
$('.tab').click(function() {
  var $target = $('#' + this.id + 'show').show().addClass('long');
  $('.tab').show();
  $contents.not($target).hide().removeClass('long');
  $(this).hide();
});

$('.close').click(function() {
  var tab = $('#' + $(this).attr('data-tab'));
  var tabContent = $(this).parent();
  
  tab.show();  
  tabContent.hide();
});
```

```css
.tab {background:red; max-width:100px; cursor: pointer;}
.close {border: 1px solid red; max-width:100px; cursor: pointer;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="tab1" class="tab">Show 1</div>
<div id="tab1show" class="tab-content">
  content 1
  <div class="close" data-tab="tab1">close</div>
  </div>



<br><br><br>
<div id="tab2" class="tab">Show 2</div>
<div id="tab2show" class="tab-content">
  content 2
  <div class="close" data-tab="tab2">close</div>
</div>

<br><br><br>
```

Comment: dosen't work. If i click show 1 and click show2 show 1 is hide.

Comment: ok Thank You but when i click show1 button from post1 i want to add class to post1 dynamicaly named post1long and dynamicaly add post2long to post2 when i click show2 jsfiddle.net/udr01vsq/25

Answer (score 1):

Just use the close event like,

```
$('.close').on('click',function(){
   $(this).closest('.tab-content').hide();
});
```

Snippet,

```js
var $contents = $('.tab-content');
$contents.slice().hide();
$('.tab').click(function() {
  var $target = $('#' + this.id + 'show').show();
  post = $target.closest('.post');
  post.addClass(post.attr('data-classes') + 'long');
  $allTargets = $contents.not($target);
  $allTargets.each(function() {
    post = $(this).closest('.post');
    post.removeClass(post.attr('data-classes') + 'long');
    $(this).hide();
  });
});
$('.close').on('click', function() {
  $(this).closest('.tab-content').hide();
});
```

```css
.tab {
  background: red;
  max-width: 100px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.close {
  border: 1px solid red;
  max-width: 100px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

[class$='long'] .tab {
  color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="post1 post" data-classes='post1'>

  <div id="tab1" class="tab">Show 1</div>
  <div id="tab1show" class="tab-content">
    content 1
    <div class="close">close</div>
  </div>
</div>

<br><br><br>
<div class="post2 post" data-classes='post2'>
  <div id="tab2" class="tab">Show 2</div>
  <div id="tab2show" class="tab-content">
    content 2
    <div class="close">close</div>
  </div>
</div>
<br><br><br>
```

Comment: ok Thank You but when i click show1 button from post1 i want to add class to post1 dynamicaly named .long and dynamicaly add .long to post2 when i click show2 https://jsfiddle.net/udr01vsq/32/

Comment: I have updated my snippet as per your comment.[By the way this is another question to ask on SO.]

Comment: when i click close class long isnt remove from this and text Show1 still white. Can you fix that? Thank you!